# Discount based on payment method redirect to dashboard

Tags: magento, magento2

I would like to ask why do my magento would redirect to dashboard after i select "Payment Method" in "Condition" section of cart price rule.

There is no error.log but in system.log. I got the following error.

```
[2017-01-18 02:15:58] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header'   tries to reorder itself towards 'global.notices', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-18 02:15:58] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.breadcrumbs' tries to reorder itself towards 'notifications', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-18 02:15:58] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'global.search' tries to reorder itself towards 'notification.messages', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-18 02:16:16] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE1_1d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e and handles : Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-01-18 02:16:19] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header' tries to reorder itself towards 'global.notices', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-18 02:16:19] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.breadcrumbs' tries to reorder itself towards 'notifications', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively. [] []
[2017-01-18 02:16:19] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'global.search' tries to reorder itself towards 'notification.messages', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
```

Will the above error cause it to redirect to dashboard?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the ajax response after "Payment Method" is selecting.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is due to some Magento files missing as my friend did not upload some files onto the svn. I reinstall and it is working now.